# Facebook Integration using C# and asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting a side project that will integrate heavily with Facebook. I'm going to use React in the front-end and it will talk to a REST ws made with asp.net core web api.

The idea is that in this API I will make the calls to Facebook.
Basically, I want to: login, get/post messages from Messenger, get/post comments and messages from a business page.

I googled a little and didn't find many resources or examples of how to do this integrations other than the Facebook documentation, that has a lot of stuff and I don't know very well where to look.

I also found this SDK for .NET but it looks a bit dated https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk and

So, my question is: Is reading the documentations entirely really the best solution?

If anyone could at least give me a hint where to go I'd be really thankful. Would it be better/easier to integrate with Facebook with other stack than c#/asp.net?

Also, if there's any other API, SDK or something already built in .NET that would help with that I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I am one of .net developers working with Facebook API more then 5 years and we have tried to use "Facebook SDK for C#". It has more issues then benefits. In result we end up with our own small Facebook API client. Basically it is just a "RestSharp" HTTP library, "Newtonsoft.Json" for serialization/deserialization and couple of generic functions where you supply Facebook API endpoint, and specify what class you expect back as generic parameter.

```
var accounts = client.Get<Accounts>("me/accounts");
var createResponse = client.Post<CreateResponse>("123456779/feed", postToCreate);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Facebook SDK for C#** works great for standard .NET

https://hackerapp.com/net/

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk

As for .NET Core I think you are out of luck at the moment. Unless you want to port it to .NET Core yourself.

Comment: Hi @Artur is it still working properly because i checked nuget package manager console. It was published in feb 2015. Actually I need the sdk to work with marketing api and in there official doc they didn't give any reference to dotnet sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Automated Customer Service bots are not uncommon in FB, but code is hard to find. I assume you had setup you App's domain and got it reviewed and approved by FB.

I tried to set a chat-bot with both, python and .NET, and I must say the python Api is much more complete, quick, and less buggy than the C# one. But, as far as I know, only the PyApi has integrated reactions (haven't tried them).

Therefore, you will need to do this manually by using the Facebook Api by sending direct GET/POST request triggered by your ASP.NET, or use some kind of inter-language platform such as IronPython to workaround the problem (which basically assembly the call, add the Key and secret, and CURL-it).

As final remark (not a very motivating one), there is documentation for post reactions, but not for message as you can see [here (posts)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactionshttp://), and [here (messenger)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a lot of the facebook operations on the client side using their javascript SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

In regards to getting up to speed on server side API calls from .NET you can check out the facebook graph api explorer.  It can be helpful for discovery.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for this topic, I had the same needs myself. After not finding a Facebook SDK to use with .NET Core, I've created a new open source .NET Standard unofficial SDK for Facebook: https://github.com/developer82/FacebookCore